# Android not showing the message by PHP echo

Tags: php, android

Basically in my android app there's 2 fields needed to be filled by user. One is a must and another one is optional.

My PHP Script:

```
<?php 
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    if(isset($_POST['smsCode'])){
            $smsCode = $_POST['smsCode'];
            $query_search = "SELECT * FROM userrequests WHERE smsCode='".$smsCode."'";
            $query_exec = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));;
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);
            //echo $rows;
            if($row == 0) {
                echo "Invalid SMS Code";
            }else{
                //Authentication code is correct
                //echo "Code matched";
                $userName = $_POST['userName'];
                $userContact = $_POST['userContact'];
                $userAddress = $_POST['userAddress'];
                $userStore = $_POST['userStore'];
                $userRequest = $_POST['userRequest'];
                $userTime = $_POST['userTime'];
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO confirmedrequest(userName,smsCode,contactNumber,userAddress,storeList,timeFrame,requestBody) VALUES ('$userName','$smsCode','$userContact','$userAddress','$userStore','$userTime','$userRequest')";
                $sql_exec = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$sql_insert) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
                if(isset($_POST['promoCode'])){
                    $promoCode = $_POST['promoCode'];
                    $query_search1 = "SELECT * FROM promocodetable WHERE promoCode='".$promoCode."'";
                    $query_exec1 = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search1) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));;
                    $row1 = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec1);
                    if($row1==0){
                     //do nothing
                    }else{
                        echo "Promo code and sms code matched";
                        $userName = $_POST['userName'];
                        $userContact = $_POST['userContact'];
                        $userAddress = $_POST['userAddress'];
                        $userStore = $_POST['userStore'];
                        $userRequest = $_POST['userRequest'];
                        $userTime = $_POST['userTime'];
                        $promoCode = $_POST['promoCode'];
                        $smsCode = $_POST['smsCode'];
                        $sql_insert1 = "INSERT INTO promorequest(userName,smsCode,contactNumber,userAddress,storeList,timeFrame,requestBody,promoCode,smsCode) VALUES ('$userName','$smsCode','$userContact','$userAddress','$userStore','$userTime','$userRequest','$promoCode','$smsCode')";
                        $sql_exec1 = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$sql_insert1) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "Code matched";
                }
            }
    }else{
        echo "Empty Code";
    }
```

And this my java code:

```
httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("www.something.com/something.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            //int smsNum = Integer.parseInt(smsCode.getText().toString());

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smsCode",smsCode.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("promoCode",promoCode.getText().toString()));// $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName",confirmName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userContact",confirmContact));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAddress",confirmAddress));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userStore",confirmStore));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userRequest",confirmRequest));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userTime",confirmTime));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            //response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("PHP Response: ", response);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Promo code and sms code matched")) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(DisplayInformation.this, "Promo Code Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent myintent = new Intent(DisplayInformation.this, Confirmation.class);

                        myintent.putExtra("confirmID", smsCode.getText().toString());
                        myintent.putExtra("confirmPromo",promoCode.getText().toString());
                        myintent.putExtra("displayName", confirmName);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayContact", confirmContact);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayAddress", confirmAddress);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayStore", confirmStore);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayTime", confirmTime);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayRequest", confirmRequest);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayFee", String.valueOf(deliveryFee));
                        startActivity(myintent);

                    }
                });
            }

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Code matched")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(DisplayInformation.this,"Code Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent myintent = new Intent(DisplayInformation.this, Confirmation.class);

                        myintent.putExtra("confirmID",smsCode.getText().toString());
                        myintent.putExtra("displayName",confirmName);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayContact",confirmContact);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayAddress",confirmAddress);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayStore",confirmStore);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayTime",confirmTime);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayRequest",confirmRequest);
                        myintent.putExtra("displayFee",String.valueOf(deliveryFee));
                        startActivity(myintent);

                    }
                });


                //startActivity(new Intent(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, UserPage.class));
            }else{
                showAlert();//testing bitbuckettt
            }





    ?>
```

The problem is that, when the smsCode is correct or incorrect, the app always show the alert message "Invalid code". 
It is able to insert the value into the database when smsCode is entered correctly but the app always show "Invalid Code".
And the Log.i shows no value. 
The app has no error.

If the user entered the correct smsCode without promoCode, I want it to go to the second if statement `if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Code matched"))`. If the user entered the correct smsCode and promoCode, I want it to go to the first if statement `if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Promo code and sms code matched"))`. But its not working now.

Comment: are you storing `smsCode` as an _INT_ in your database?

Comment: @M.Doye its stored as TEXT